# FreeText COUNT query on multiple tables is super slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, freetext

I have two tables:

```
**Product**
ID
Name
SKU

**Brand**
ID
Name
```

Product table has about 120K records
Brand table has 30K records

I need to find count of all the products with name and  brand matching a specific keyword.

I use freetext 'contains' like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   Product
       inner join Brand 
         on Product.BrandID = Brand.ID
WHERE  (contains(Product.Name, 'pants') 
   or 
            contains(Brand.Name, 'pants'))
```

This query takes about **17 secs.**
I rebuilt the FreeText index before running this query.

If I only check for Product.Name. They query is less then 1 sec. Same, if I only check the Brand.Name.  The issue occurs if I use OR condition.

If I switch query to use LIKE:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   Product
       inner join Brand 
         on Product.BrandID = Brand.ID
WHERE   Product.Name LIKE '%pants%'
   or 
            Brand.Name LIKE '%pants%'
```

It takes **1 secs.**

I read on MSDN that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

> To search on multiple tables, use a
>   joined table in your FROM clause to
>   search on a result set that is the
>   product of two or more tables.

So I added an INNER JOINED table to FROM:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM   (select Product.Name ProductName, Product.SKU ProductSKU, Brand.Name as BrandName FROM Product
       inner join Brand 
         on product.BrandID = Brand.ID) as TempTable
WHERE  

     contains(TempTable.ProductName, 'pants') 
     or 
            contains(TempTable.BrandName, 'pants')
```

This results in error:
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'ProductName' because it is not full-text indexed.

So the question is - why OR condition could be causing such as slow query?

Comment: Do you have an index on Product.BrandID?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on Product.BrandID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of trial an error I found a solution that seems to work. It involves creating an indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ProductBrand]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT     dbo.Product.ID, dbo.Product.Name, dbo.Product.SKU, dbo.Brand.Name AS BrandName
FROM         dbo.Product INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Brand ON dbo.Product.BrandID = dbo.Brand.ID

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_VW_PRODUCTBRAND_ID 
    ON vw_ProductBrand (ID);
GO
```

If I run the following query:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO

SELECT count(*) 
FROM   Product
       inner join vw_ProductBrand
         on Product.BrandID =  vw_ProductBrand.ID
WHERE  (contains(vw_ProductBrand.Name, 'pants') 
   or 
            contains( vw_ProductBrand.BrandName, 'pants'))
```

It now takes **1 sec** again.

Comment: THANK YOU!!.  Instead of doing the OR, I went ahead and combined everything into a single contains clause after adding the index to a view.  Runs 10 times faster now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem but i fixed it with union, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Product
       inner join Brand 
         on Product.BrandID = Brand.ID
WHERE contains(Product.Name, 'pants') 

UNION

SELECT *
FROM   Product
       inner join Brand 
         on Product.BrandID = Brand.ID
WHERE contains(Brand.Name, 'pants'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT count(*) 
    FROM Product
    INNER JOIN Brand ON Product.BrandID = Brand.ID
    WHERE CONTAINS((Product.Name, Brand.Name), 'pants')
```

Comment: I get an error:
Fulltext predicate references columns from two different tables or indexed views 'Product' and 'Brand' which is not allowed.

Comment: Oh well; it was worth a try! Another idea: I wonder if you could join the two tables in a View, and then query the View?