# CONTAINSTABLE issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set up full-text indexing in my database along with a `CONTAINSTABLE` so users can search on the website against product SKUs & product names.  I have set up a customization on the search, to where it strips the hyphen (-) out of a users search and in the database column when it grabs values.  I have run into an issue on the search where searching '10-10' results in a broken page, with the error listing as so :

```
Source:.Net SqlClient Data Provider
Message:Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Stack Trace:
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

The search works great otherwise, and I know that the hypen shouldn't be an issue, because if I search 'tw5-c' I get a few results returned.  Is it possible that too many results are being returned and the connection is timing-out?

Here is the SQL CONTAINSTABLE statement:

```
INSERT @searchfilter (productid, variantID, SearchRank)
        SELECT p.ProductID, pv.VariantID, 100 from dbo.Product p with(NOLOCK)
            JOIN dbo.ProductVariant pv with(NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID 
                JOIN dbo.ProductStore ps with(NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = ps.ProductID and ps.StoreID = @storeID
                WHERE 
                ( REPLACE(p.SKU,'-','') LIKE '%' + @searchstr + '%' )
                OR
                ( REPLACE(p.Name,'-','') LIKE '%' + @searchstr + '%' )
        UNION
        SELECT p.ProductID, pv.VariantID,
               case
                    when psearch.[KEY] is not null then psearch.Rank
                    when pvsearch.[KEY] is not null then pvsearch.Rank
                    else 1
                end
                as SearchRank
            from dbo.Product p with(NOLOCK)
            JOIN dbo.ProductVariant pv with(NOLOCK) on p.ProductID = pv.ProductID
            -- fulltext indexing changes for more accurate searches
            join CONTAINSTABLE(Product, *, @ftssearchstring) psearch ON p.ProductID = psearch.[KEY]
            left join CONTAINSTABLE(ProductVariant, *, @ftssearchstring) pvsearch ON pv.VariantID = pvsearch.[KEY]
```

Comment: based on your Query, what you are doing you should be fine from a syntax perspective but containstables isn't great for JOINS  see another previous answer of mine.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933761/can-containstable-be-told-which-column-to-look-in-per-search-term/27934567#27934567

Comment: On a related note, your first query in the Union will have performance issues due to your search criteria being [non-sargable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).  I know that you said that it works, but if you look at your query plan, I think you'll find that it's always performing a table scan.

Comment: Is your timeout setting set to the default of 30 seconds?  How big are those tables?  By it's very nature, CONTAINSTABLE returns a table with no indexes.  So you're performing a poorly-performing query unioned with a query that is performing multiple table scans.  It seems to me that this might just be a case of poor query optimization.  Can you post your query plan?