# How CONTAINSTABLE works with many search words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, containstable

For example I got a table `Companies`. There is a field `FullName` in it, on which I got full-text index. Then I join that table with `CONTAINSTABLE` with `@search_word` like `"company*" AND "name*" AND "oil*" AND "propan*" AND "liquid*"...` from 1 to 10 words.

And I know that words (with variants `*`) got this number of matches:

- company - 10k
- name - 5k
- oil - 2k
- propan - 1k
- liquid - 500
- all words above in 1 row - 300 matches

So, if I will search in that order:

`@search = '"company*" AND "name*" AND "oil*" AND "propan*" AND "liquid*"'`

and in that order:

`@search = '"liquid*" AND "propan*" AND "oil*" AND "name*" AND "company*"'`

```
SELECT [FullName]
FROM dbo.Companies c
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (dbo.Companies, [FullName], @search) as s ON s.[KEY] = c.[KEY_FIELD];
```

Will I have any differences in speed of my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a few tests monitoring "Query costs" of the Actual Execution Plan.

It seems overall cost of CONTAINSTABLE over any number of words joined in a search phrase with **"AND"** is equal to the cost of the **least** popular of those words alone.

Overall cost of CONTAINSTABLE over any number of words joined with **"OR"** is equal to the cost of the **most** popular of those words alone.

That suggests Full-Text Search engine prioritizes words from the search string in accordance with their popularity (occurrence count) in the index. Hence I think there would be no benefit in trying to pre-order search string words on the client.

Here are my Full-Text Search tests:

```
Declare @Word1        nvarchar(50) = N'"Word1*"';
Declare @Word2        nvarchar(50) = N'"Word2*"';
Declare @SearchString nvarchar(100) = '';

PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' Start';
Set @SearchString = @Word1;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
Set @SearchString = @Word2;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
Set @SearchString = @Word1 + ' AND ' + @Word2;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
Set @SearchString = @Word2 + ' AND ' + @Word1;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
Set @SearchString = @Word1 + ' OR ' + @Word2;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
Set @SearchString = @Word2 + ' OR ' + @Word1;
Select * From CONTAINSTABLE([Table], [Field], @SearchString);
PRINT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, SYSDATETIME(), 121), 12, 11) + ' ' + @SearchString;
```

Please replace `[Table], [Field]` with your actual Full-Text-indexed table and field names, and set `@Word1` and `@Word2` to popular and rear words from your data set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do some research after posting a question and they are similar to your answer. Also I have found this very useful post about full-text search execution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750870/sql-serve-full-text-search-with-containstable-is-very-slow-when-used-in-join

Comment: @gofr1 Thanks for the link. It is interesting indeed.