# Add SQL query options to NHibernate query

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm working with some code that generates ICriteria queries for NHibernate. They get executed using ActiveRecord and ActiveRecordMediator.FindAll()

For certain queries, I need to optimise them by adding on an `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` hint at the end of the SELECT statement. Is there a quick way I can do this?

I don't want to rewrite the queries using plain SQL. Well, I'd love to, but they're too complicated. But if, for example,  there's an easy way I can trap and modify the SQL before it's pumped off to SQL Server, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement an IInterceptor and do your modifications in OnPrepareStatement(). Then pass your interceptor to ISessionFactory.OpenSession().

[Here's an example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/29/poor-manrsquos-guide-to-database-optimization-by-the-marquis.aspx).

Or you could try registering a custom function in your dialect. ([example](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/13/registering-freetext-or-contains-functions-into-a-nhibernate-dialect.aspx))

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this. It works, although it was quite painful getting there. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

While answer of Mauricio Scheffer is extremly useful I've desided to extend it with working sample for implementing Interceptor to be used with NHibernate and Castle Active Records.

***The Interceptor***

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.SqlCommand;

namespace Common.FTS
{

public class FtsHashInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private static FtsHashInterceptor instance = new FtsHashInterceptor();

    protected FtsHashInterceptor() { }

    public static FtsHashInterceptor Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set { instance = value; }
    }

    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        return sql.Replace("inner join Product fts1_", "inner hash join Product fts1_");
    }
}
}
```

***Wiring up the Interceptor with a Facility***

```
using Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework;
using Castle.Core.Configuration;
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using NHibernate;

namespace Common.FTS
{
/// 
/// Allows for the system to pick up the audit facility which will be used to
/// audit all transactions in the system.
/// 
public class FtsHashFacility : IFacility
{
    #region IFacility Members

    public void Init(IKernel kernel, IConfiguration facilityConfig)
    {
        InterceptorFactory.Create = new InterceptorFactory.CreateInterceptor(CreateFtsHashInterceptor);
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        // Nothing to terminate
    }

    #endregion

    private IInterceptor CreateFtsHashInterceptor()
    {
        return FtsHashInterceptor.Instance;
    }
}
}
```

The class above creates a Facility for Active Record. We wire this up in the Global.asax.cs file like so:

```
static private IWindsorContainer _container;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer(Server.MapPath("~/config/windsor.config"));
    var app = _container.Resolve();
    app.RegisterFacilities(_container);
    app.RegisterComponents(_container);
}
}
```

In the Application.cs file we add the facility as such:

```
public void RegisterFacilities(IWindsorContainer container)
{
container.AddFacility("fts.support", new FtsHashFacility());
}
```

***Conclusion***
The container now contains the facility which will wire up the *Full Text Search* interceptor which will intercept all ActiveRecordMediator calls.

We have not changed a line of code in our existing system, yet we have added the ability to analyse all of our SQL Request operations in a simple yet effective manner.

Special Thanks to [Donn Felker](http://blog.donnfelker.com)